# ссылочные типы метода конструктор

Tags: java, классы, методы

```
class Apple {
     Apple getPeeled() {
          return Peeler.peel(tihis);
     }
}
```

Что значит тип `Apple` перед методом `getPeeled`? Не понимаю такой конструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это имя класса, которое содержит этот метод. Это означает, что данный метод возвращает ссылку на объект типа `Apple`.

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что метод должен обязательно возвращать нечто, что будет типа `Apple`

Как, например, `int getSomething()` показывает, что возвращаемым значением должно быть целое число